# Error information in CustomError Page

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, webforms

I want to have a custom error page that displays some error information, but not the stack trace.
I would like for it to display the information for the offending page and the line number.

The default SERVER ERROR IN APPLICATION page shows the url/line number and surrounding code/stack trace.

I just want the url/line number to appear somewhere inside a prettier custom error page. That way our code isn't exposed when an error is thrown, but I can still find the error quickly by url/line number.

I already have custom error pages turned on. I just want to add additional information to them.
I'm using C#.NET 4.0 and webforms.

Comment: I think that this link will help you http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/Displaying-a-Custom-Error-Page-cs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question I have had for a while and for the longest time though it was not possible, so I did some research and found a solution.  You need to use the `StackFrame` object from the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.  I just put together an example and it appears to have worked.

```
try
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 0;
    litDebug.Text = (a / b).ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    StackTrace st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
    StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
    litDebug.Text = "" +
        "<br />File Name: " + sf.GetFileName() +
        "<br />Method Name: " + sf.GetMethod().Name +
        "<br />Error Line Number: " + sf.GetFileLineNumber() +
        "<br />Error Column Number: " + sf.GetFileColumnNumber();
}
```

The page output is:

```
File Name: c:\inetpub\www.website.com\dev\error.aspx.cs
Method Name: Page_Load
Error Line Number: 17
Error Column Number: 4
```

The only questionable item is the Error Column Number - everything else matches up perfectly.